# Problem with Aiohttp.ClientSession and large number of requests with proxy

Tags: sockets, tcp, proxy, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I create a lot of sessions aiohttp.ClientSession and send requests via http-proxy.

Everything works fine until I try to send more than 4-5k requests at the same time, but when I try to create more than 5k sessions and send requests with http-proxies I get the following behavior: after 3-4k requests sent successfully, I stop getting output from printers (which shows the number of requests), and nothing happens, I get no response from requests and no errors like TimeoutError, ClientHttpProxyError etc. The event loop doesn't stop and any open connections are not closed.

Netstat shows a bunch of connections with a "close_wait" status

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9l6wS.png)

If I don't use proxy, everything is fine, after some time, around 40-50 seconds, I get the result of processing all requests.

I tried to set timeout, in request configuration "session.get(timeout=20)", and get the following, if I set timeout less than 20 seconds, I start getting TimeoutError's as it should be, and program finishes cycle, but if set timeout value more than 20 seconds, like - 50, then I get exactly same result as I described in the beginning.

I want to be able to set timeout value higher than 20 seconds, and get the result of all requests instead of freezing event loop (or something else, but it looks like

Example code:

```
`import requests
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from datetime import datetime
import random
import time    

with open(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\proxy.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    proxies = f.read().split('\n')

async def create_sessions():
    sessions = []
    for i in range(10000):
        session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
        sessions.append(session)
    return sessions
    
done = 0

async def send_req(session, n, proxy):
    url = f'https://www.google.com/search?q=test'
    try:
        async with session.get(url, timeout=20, proxy = proxy) as resp:
            print(resp.status)
            # await resp.text()
            # print(resp.status)
            global done
            done+=1
            print(f"Requests done: {done}")
        return resp.status
    except Exception as e:
        print(e.__class__.__name__)
    finally:
        await session.close()

async def main():
    sessions = await create_sessions()
    tasks = []
    for n, session in enumerate(sessions):
        dsn = random.choice(proxies)
        parts = dsn.split(':')
        proxy = f"http://{parts[2]}:{parts[3]}@{parts[0]}:{parts[1]}"
        # print(proxy)

        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(send_req(session, n, proxy=proxy)))
    start = datetime.now()

    result = []
    for task in tasks:
        result.append(await task)
    print(len(list(filter(lambda x:x == 200, result))))
    print(datetime.now()-start)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.stop()
time.sleep(1)
loop.close()``
```